# Поиск элемента в регулярном выражении

Tags: java, html, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день! Пишу регулярное выражение для автоматической загрузки файлов с сайта, столкнулся с проблемой не могу найти элемент с тегом `<a href>`
HTML:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/ru/press/news/40586-maksim-bystrov-prinyal-uchastie-vo-vserossiyskom-soveshchanii-po-itogam-podgotovki"><strong>Максим Быстров принял участие во Всероссийском совещании по итогам подготовки к ОЗП 2017-2018 годов</strong></a></span>
```

Моя регулярка:`<div class="views-field views-field-title">[^&/]+<span class="field-content"><a href="([^&/]+)"><strong>([^&/]+)</strong></a></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем выражении несколько проблем.
Во-первых, Вы не экранируете специальные символы (а именно - слэш).
Во-вторых, Вы очень странным образом захватываете пробельные символы. Для этого есть специальный синтаксис - \s.
В третьих, чтобы сделать регулярное выражение более читаемым, группы в нем стоит именовать.
Вот пример более-менее подходящего Вам выражения:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-title">\s*<span class="field-content">\s*<a href="(?<ref>[^"]*)">\s*<strong>(?<text>[^<]*)<\/strong>\s*<\/a>\s*<\/span>
```

[Тут можно посмотреть, как оно работает](https://regex101.com/r/OtsNvr/1).

А вообще, в таких случаях лучше использовать уже готовые парсеры, и искать нужные Вам данные через [XPath](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).